# Python. Уникальные и ключ и значение в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прошу помощи.
Есть словарь:

```
my_dict = {'aaa': 40, 'aaa': 40, 'aaa': 30, 'bbb': 40, 'bbb': 30, 'bbb': 40}
```

не соображу, как оставить в словаре только уникальные ключ/значение. В результате должно быть:

```
my_dict = {'aaa': 40, 'aaa': 30, 'bbb': 40, 'bbb': 30}
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить: `my_dict = {'aaa': 40, 'aaa': 30, 'bbb': 40, 'bbb': 30}; print(my_dict)` ;-)

Comment: Нужен весь код. А именно откуда берутся значения в словаре

Comment: Код ещё не писал. По задумке код будет считывать с файла .txt.

Comment: По вашему совету запустил. Я новичок в питоне. Я так понимаю, что возможностями словаря такую задачу не решу. В этот файл пользователи будут вносить построчно по два элемента - иногда они будут повторяться или по ключу или по значению. Я хотел отсечь эти пары. Если я правильно понимаю возможностями словаря этого не сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Никак. Смысл словаря в том, что он идентифицирует элементы только по ключу. Поэтому элементы с тем же ключом, но другим значением, будут просто перезатирать существующие элементы.

Если вам нужно хранить уникальные пары значений, то используйте `set` из кортежей:

```
my_set = {('aaa', 40), ('aaa', 40), ('aaa', 30),
          ('bbb', 40), ('bbb', 30), ('bbb', 40)}

print(my_set)
# Остались только уникальные пары:
# {('aaa', 40), ('aaa', 30), ('bbb', 30), ('bbb', 40)}
```

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @Дмитрий Либо, например, подставить список в value словаря, типа, как-то так: `my_dict = {'aaa': [30,40], 'bbb': [30,40]}` как вам нравится и в зависимости от задачи

Comment: @nobody, тогда уж в value стоит поставить не списки, а set, чтобы дубли сразу схлопывались ) Тоже вариант, но вложенные контейнеры часто бывают неудобными в работе, это нужно смотреть по ситуации.